# Garageband Drum Question - half measures

Tags: garageband

I have a song that is primarily in 4/4 but has two places where I had an extra half measure.

So for part of the song where I go from the verse to the chorus it is on the 3rd beat (half was in the middle of the measure).

For some reason, even though I use the exact same length (12 measures) for the "verse" part of the drummer, the entrance is automatically modified to some kind of fill instead of a  normal verse entry and is messing me up.

How can I get it to just lock into staying the same as the start of the track?  (Hope this makes sense).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did

1. Use an empty 1/2 measure to make the drum fill sound right (even though it's in the wrong place)
2. Create a midi track just below your drum track, and set the midi instrument to the same one that the drum is using
3. Copy/paste the drum track into the midi track and now mute the drum track (note: opt-drag doesn't work here, has to be copy/paste)
4. Now edit the midi track as needed: drag left to close the empty 1/2 measure in the midi track

Answer (score 0):

Set it to 4/8 instead of 4/4 for a quick workaround.